# How to stop Azure resource group list always revert to filtering on a specific subscription?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I would like to be able to quickly list resource groups (across all Azure subscriptions).

It's easy to save this as a view or as part of a dashboard:

[image: resource groups]

However, next time I return to that view or dashboard, the `Subscription` filter reverts to a particular subscription (`Production` in my case):

[image: resource groups filtered]

As can be seen, the filter on `Subscription` can't be removed.  While it can be edited to `all`, this never persists across browser sessions, even if the view is saved.

How can I stop this unwanted filtering from reappearing every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I stop this unwanted filtering from reappearing every time?

You can set the default subscription filtering in Settings > Directories + subscriptions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I would never have found that!